# Как создать VPN для Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, openvpn

Суть вопроса:
Я создаю приложение на **Android**, а для его нормального функционирования мне нужно менять **IP**, я написал алгоритм в котором при подключении/отключении передачи данных IP меняется, однако если использовать Wi-Fi этот способ не работает, поэтому следующим вариантом стало поставить **VPN**, перелопатив кучу информации в интернете я ничего работающего не нашел. Прошу помочь реализовать VPN или есть другие способы менять IP **(обходя случай с Wi-Fi)**.

Вот пример старой реализации

```
public class MyVpnService extends VpnService {
    private Thread mThread;
    private ParcelFileDescriptor mInterface;
    //a. Configure a builder for the interface.
    Builder builder = new Builder();

    // Services interface
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Start a new session by creating a new thread.
        mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //a. Configure the TUN and get the interface.
                    mInterface = builder.setSession("MyVPNService")
                            .addAddress("192.168.0.1", 24)
                            .addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")
                            .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0).establish();
                    //b. Packets to be sent are queued in this input stream.
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(
                            mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
                    //b. Packets received need to be written to this output stream.
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                            mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
                    //c. The UDP channel can be used to pass/get ip package to/from server
                    DatagramChannel tunnel = DatagramChannel.open();
                    // Connect to the server, localhost is used for demonstration only.
                    tunnel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8087));
                    //d. Protect this socket, so package send by it will not be feedback to the vpn service.
                    protect(tunnel.socket());
                    //e. Use a loop to pass packets.
                    while (true) {
                        //get packet with in
                        //put packet to tunnel
                        //get packet form tunnel
                        //return packet with out
                        //sleep is a must
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Catch any exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (mInterface != null) {
                            mInterface.close();
                            mInterface = null;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }

        }, "MyVpnRunnable");

        //start the service
        mThread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread.interrupt();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Внимательно проверив нашел некоторые ошибки и исправил их, теперь появился новый вопрос в этой части кода

```
protect(tunnel.socket());
                    //e. Use a loop to pass packets.
                    while (true) {
                        //get packet with in
                        //put packet to tunnel
                        //get packet form tunnel
                        //return packet with out
                        //sleep is a must
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
```

Прошу объяснить мне что именно сюда писать чтобы заработало VPN соединение.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону [VpnService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) ([VpnBuilder)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html), вот [пример](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mobisoft/blog/231827/) приложения VPN клиента (можете включить его код в своё приложение).

Comment: Да, я пробовал этот способ, но при интернет соединении ничего не грузится, в чем могла быть проблема?

Comment: @АртикКулешов, я не видел вашего кода, поэтому трудно сказать почему что-то не работало.

Comment: я добавил код старой версии и обновил вопрос(дописан в конце)

Answer (score 1):

**VpnService** - это базовый класс для приложений для расширения и создания собственных VPN-решений. Oн создает виртуальный сетевой интерфейс, настраивает адреса и правила маршрутизации и возвращает дескриптор файла в приложение. Каждое чтение из дескриптора извлекает исходящий пакет, который был перенаправлен на интерфейс. Каждая запись в дескриптор вводит входящий пакет так же, как он был получен из интерфейса.

Интерфейс работает в Internet Protocol (IP), поэтому пакеты всегда запускаются с заголовками IP. Затем приложение завершает VPN-соединение, обрабатывая и обменивая пакеты с удаленным сервером по туннелю.

[VpnService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html)

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить мне как это прописать кодом? :)